# How to find a constant of integration when you're told to use Neumann conditions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I am trying to follow a book example where I need to solve the following ODE on a circular domain:
$$\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{dT}{dr} \right) = -A$$
subject to two Neumann boundary conditions: boundedness at $r = 0$ and 
$$\frac{dT(R)}{dr} = B,$$ where $A$ and $B$ are known constants.

The solution of the differential equation is:
$$T(r) = -Ar^2 + c_1 \ln r + c_2,$$
where the boundedness condition forces $c_1 = 0$. So how can I use the other condition to find $c_2$ when it's going to disappear when I take the derivative? The text presents it as if it's intuitively obvious but I don't see how it's possible. Am I misunderstanding something? I don't see how I have any free parameters in applying the other Neumann condition.

Comment: I think your right that the question doen't have an answer

Answer (score 1):

The value of $c_2$ cannot be determined from the information given. If the answer to the problem would be: 
$$
T(r) = -Ar^2 + c_2,
$$
where $c_2$ is an arbitrary real constant.

That was assuming that *all* solutions were expected. If the goal is to find just one, then take a convenient value for $c_2$, such as $0$.